# Pushing into Vector millions of objects = bad-alloc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, bad-alloc

I am compiling following code VS2012 - 32BIT. I know that **max_size()** returns

**"maximum potential size the container can reach" which is in my case: 1.073.741.823** (yeay)

So how can i know, how many object my container can really store? (I have 64gb RAM)

```
unsigned int = 100000000;
vector<int*> data;
std::cout<<"max cap: "<<data.max_size()<<std::endl;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < operationUnit; i++)
data.push_back(new int());
```

This will end-up in a bad-alloc. However, as i am targetting x64 this problem doesn't occur, as the max-cap is much higher, but i still cannot figure the exact elements, when i would like to reduce it down to clamp user-input.

thanks!

Comment: And how much user input are you expecting, on average?

Comment: You're worried users might input more than a *trillion* integers?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to know the maximum number of elements you can store? There isn't a hard number, just add the elements as you need them and be ready to handle an exception (if you can actually do something about it).

Comment: this code is a break-down, to give a understanding, don't stick on the fact, that no user will input so much data. So the question is, how i can determine the max-size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is OS dependent ofcourse, but the results would be, similar for every one. For example when run as 32bit executable, consistenly a build with VS2012 will stop at 26,906,977 elements in a vector of `int*`, not posing a threat to your memory (not even by close).

Now it gets interesting when you build a 64bit version, in which case, throwing a `bad_alloc` happens when (almost) all your memory is drained. In that case, no C++ not any other language can protect you.

In the screenshot that follows I'm posting an example of this happening: by the time `bad_alloc` gets thrown, the program is in no position to catch it or do anything with it. The OS steps in and kills every process and memory is deallocated at once (see graph). In the respective 32 version the exception was caught normally and deallocation would take about 10 minutes.

Now this is a very simplistic way of seeing this, I'm sure OS gurus could supply more insights but feel free to try this at home (and burn out some memory - I can't stop thinking that I can smell something burnt after this)

[image: exceeding 16GB of memory]

the code in the screenshot

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;


int main() 
{

    vector<int*> maxV;

    try 
    {
        while (true) maxV.push_back(new int);
    } 
    catch (bad_alloc &e) 
    {
        cout << "I caught bad alloc at element no " << maxV.size() << "\n";
        for (auto i : maxV) delete i;
    } 
    catch (exception &e) 
    {
        cout << "Some other exception happened at element no " << maxV.size() << "\n";
        for (auto i : maxV) delete i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all wonderfull explanation! thank you very much for that. So 32bit will stop @26,906,977. and 64 bit would run till the memory burns completely? Why are those concepts different? Why is there a somehow fixed limitation with 32bit and 64bit not? Does it have any connection to contiguous memory? When you answer those things, the question is for me answered! thanks! :)

Comment: Theoretically a 64-bit architecture can address 16.8 million TB of memory, or 2^64 bytes whereas a 32-bit one only up to 2^32 bytes or 4GB. In a sense this means that out of your 64 GB of memory, only 4 can be utilized by a 32-bit architecture simply because memory address numbers larger than 2^32 are beyond it

Comment: Why is it 10 minutes to recover the memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. OS could totally run out of memory. You may find that using `deque` data structure can become larger before error than `vector` for huge amounts of data, as the data is not contiguous and so it is less effected by memory fragmentation, which can be significant when you end up allocating more than half your entire memory..

Comment: but how can the OS run out of memory, when i have 64 GIG Ram? I mean there must be another limitation than that?

Comment: @user1767754 What happens if you have already loaded 10 of this program?

Comment: vector requires *contiguous* memory to be available, not just memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk hmmm now that makes sense